# Regex / Filter Numerics From a String

Tags: regex, string, filter, expression

Using Regex, From the follow string..

M8684977100203MOB20/14071M116980

I am trying to filter out the following numerics..

4977100203

I have tried multiple methods and failed miserably. Any assistance?

Comment: `M\d{3}(\d*)M` didn't work?  If by "filter out" you mean "remove" perhaps `(.*M\d{3})\d*(M.*)`...

Comment: Filter means remove or capture?

Comment: @paddy: I'm not very concerned about the brackets, but thank you...  (And corrected)

Comment: Also in which language as it might change slightly...?

Comment: Can you show us what you have done?

Answer (score 0):

In case you always have 3 digits before the 10 digits you are looking for. The 10 digits are stored on group \1:

```
M\d{3}(\d{10})
```

... you can see that it works in http://rubular.com/r/sIstkRnrWI

```
M\d{3}([\d]+)M
```

... for a variable number of digits to be matched in group \1. http://rubular.com/r/34BH2QtAWK

By the way, which application are you using for the regex? You must take into account escape characters for all this.

Using sed+bash:

```
echo 'M8684977100203MOB20/14071M116980' | sed -e 's/M[0-9]\{3\}\([^M]\+\).*/\1/g'
```

returns the desired string.